# Accessing application class from a service

Tags: android, global-variables

To store values as global variables, I read that the Application class can be used. I intend to take username and password from the main activity, store them in application class variables and start a new activity, then fetch these values inside a service started in the new activity, however, I get null values on using the getter methods I defined in my application class.

**My Application Class :**

```
public class MyApp extends Application
{
  private String uid;
  private String upwd;

  @Override
  public void onCreate()
  {
      super.onCreate();
  } 

  public void setUID(String value)
  {
      uid = value;
  }

  public void setPWD(String value)
  {
      upwd = value; 
  }

  public String getUID()
  {
      return uid;
  }

  public String getPWD()
  {
      return upwd;
  }
}
```

**In My Main Activity:**

```
  public void setvalues()
  {
        unameval = Unametxtfield.getText().toString();
        pswrdval =  Pswrdtxtfield.getText().toString();     
        ((MyApp)this.getApplicationContext()).setUID(unameval);
        ((MyApp)this.getApplicationContext()).setPWD(pswrdval);
  }
```

**Inside the Service My Second Activity:**

```
public void fetchvalues()
{
      String uname = ((MyApp).getApplicationContext()).getUID();
      String upswrd = ((MyApp).getApplicationContext()).getPWD();
}
```

**Android Manifest:**

```
<application
        android:name="MyApp"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!-- A Service here -->
     <service
        android:name="Service1"
        android:process=":myapp_service1" >
    </service> 


    <!-- A service in which I do the fetching of uname and pswd -->
     <service 
        android:name="Service2"
        android:process=":myapp_Service2" >
     </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".Second_Activity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/activityname" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/Firstactivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Note: I read somewhere that application class wont work when you are using it over mutliple processes(which I think i'm doing), is this true?

Comment: it is true. you cannot use this method over several processes.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: I already switched to shared preferences and got it working no problem but I want to learn why the earlier method didn't work, thanks anyway

Comment: a Singleton won't work either. Same reason as Application object: different processes means different VM instances. They cannot communicate directly and share same memory space.

Comment: Is the service running as an isolated process?